# WPF get all Controls "Content"

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

How would check, if a WPF control has a Content-Variable?

I'm iterating through all of the controls using this Code:

```
public void Translate(Visual myVisual)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(myVisual); i++)
    {
        // Retrieve child visual at specified index value.
        Visual childVisual = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(myVisual, i);

        //How can I check wether childVisual has a Content-Variable or hasn't?
        //So check if this: childVisual.Content is existing

        // Enumerate children of the child visual object.
        Translate(childVisual);
    }
}
```

You propably coud do the following for every Control-Type:

```
if(visualChild is CheckBox)
     //cast it to CheckBox etc.
```

But that's dirty, is there any other possibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to check if your `Visual` is a `ContentControl`.  Generally, all WPF controls that have a `Content` property derive from `ContentControl`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(myVisual); i++)
{
    // Retrieve child visual at specified index value.
    Visual childVisual = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(myVisual, i);

    //How can I check whether childVisual has a Content-Variable or hasn't?
    var childContentVisual = childVisual as ContentControl;
    if(childContentVisual != null)
    {
        var content = childContentVisual.Content;
        ...
    }

    // Enumerate children of the child visual object.
    Translate(childVisual);
}
```

You could also use reflection to see if a Content property exists, but that's slower and more cumbersome.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know this Class is existing. Solved